# Are hypotheses typically expressed in terms of the expectation of Variables or can we express them in terms of the shape parameters as well?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, gamma-distribution

Say one has data from an experiment (control and treatment) that follows a gamma distribution. So:

$$X_{A,B} \sim \frac{\beta^{\alpha}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$$

where A is control and B is treatment.

Would one typically formulate a hypothesis in terms of

$$H_{0}\colon \mu_A \geq \mu_B $$

or say,

$$H_{0}\colon \beta_A \geq \beta_B? $$

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the analysis? E.g. If you'd do a t-test for normally distributed variables you'd use the means and state $H_0:μ_B - μ_A= 0$, but if you study a multivariable regression you'd focus on the beta's ($β$) and state $H_0:β_B=0$ *conditional on additional predictors*.

Comment: @IWS I wonder what interpretation you are making of this question, given that $\beta_B=0$ is not even a valid value of the shape parameter. User1172468: you might derive some insight by contemplating tests of a correlation coefficient $\rho$ in the Binormal setting, because $\rho$ is a shape parameter.

Comment: @whuber excuse me I seem to have misread the question and assumed it was about any hypothesis testing in general. In my examples I referred to a t-test, and the beta was meant as a regression coefficient (as in the $y=a+bx$ sense, where $H_0$ would be b=0). As the beta the OP implied is a shape parameter of the gamma distribution I seem to be way off with my comment. My apologies again.

Comment: @user1172468 Beware -- because $\beta$ is a rate parameter, not a scale parameter, your two nulls go in opposite directions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just a matter of what is substantially interesting to the authors. For example, we may be interested in the difference in mean income between men and women (typically women will earn on average less than men). But we could also get insights by comparing the variability of income between men and women (the standard deviation is typically smaller for women then for men). Both, and more, comparisons are legitimate, but they tell different stories. So you first need to choose the story, than look for the parameters that allow you to quantify that story. If you are interested in differences in shape, and the shape parameters capture that aspect, then by all means go for it. Otherwise, don't.